# ATS Proof: Why does this static if need greater than or equal to?

Tags: if-statement, theorem-proving, ats

I was writing a proof of `a*0=0` and I stumbled on some strangeness. Why does the `sif a >= 0` on line 7 need to be a `>=`, and does not compile when its just `sif > 0`?

```
prfn mul_ax0_0 {a:int} () : MUL(a,0,0) =
let
    prfun auxnat {a:nat} .<a>. () : MUL(a,0,0) =
        sif a == 0 then MULbas()
        else MULind(auxnat{a-1}())
in
    sif a >= 0 then auxnat{a}() // line 7
    else MULneg(auxnat{~a}())
end

implement main0 () = ()
```

Intuitively, the `a=0` should be handled fine by either path, yet only the first path works.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MULneg is declared as follows:

```
  | {m:pos}{n:int}{p:int}
    MULneg (~(m), n, ~(p)) of MUL_prop (m, n, p)
```

Note that 'm' is required to be positive. In your case, 'm' is '~a'. If
you use '>' instead of '>=', then it cannot be inferred that '~a > 0' holds
when the test 'a > 0' fails.